# Populating a static/const with an environment variable at runtime in Rust

Tags: static, environment-variables, rust, constants

I'm trying to load passwords and sensitive data from the system's environment when my service starts up. I've tried a number of different ways but can't seem to figure out the right way to do this in Rust.

```
const PASSWORD: String = var("PASSWORD").unwrap();
```

Doesn't work because `method calls in constants are limited to constant  inherent methods`. The same applies to `static` (except the error says statics, obviously).

The other way I've seen to do it is

```
const PASSWORD: &'static str = env!("PASSWORD");
```

But the problem with that is it will be defined at compile time as `env!` is a macro (at least that is my understanding).

I also considered simply wrapping the call to `var("...").unwrap()` in a function but that solution doesn't really sit right with me, and would also allow the values to change throughout runtime AND not validate them when the service starts.

As you can tell I'm new to Rust. I'd really appreciate if in your answer you could not just explain how to load the const/static at runtime but also explain why what I'm doing is dumb and wrong :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`const` and `static` fill different roles in Rust.

`const` does not only mean a constant, it means a *compile-time* constant, a value determined at compile-time and inscribed in the read-only memory of the program. It is not suitable for your usecase.

`static` means a global variable, with a lifetime that will span the entire program. It may be mutable, in which case it must be `Sync` to avoid concurrent modifications. A `static` variable must be initialized from a constant, in order to be available from the start of the program.

So, how to read a variable at run-time and have it available? Well, a clean solution would be to avoid globals altogether...

... but since it can be convenient, there is a crate for it: [`lazy_static!`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static).

```
use std::env::var;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref PASSWORD: String = var("PASSWORD").unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", *PASSWORD);
}
```

On first access to the variable, the expression is executed to load its value, the value is then memoized and available until the end of the program.

Comment: Is there a better way? I'd prefer the variables to be loaded and have their presence validated at the time the service starts rather than when they are first requested. But if you don't like globals how else would you handle environment variables? Assuming they're not to change after the service starts would there be somewhere better I could put them?

Comment: @dave: that's how globals are handled in Rust, just access them at the first opportunity (in main) and they will be loaded at the earliest possible point. As for not using globals, why not simply retrieve the password in a variable and then pass it (via arguments) to whoever needs it? Same functionality, but it makes it explicit which block of code accesses the password.

Comment: Haha, almost too simple. But yeah I should probably just do it that way and validate their presence while I load them. Thanks for the shot of clarity.

Comment: `lazy_static` crate will lead to error `multiple matching crates for `lazy_static``.

Comment: I needed `ref`:
`static ref PASSWORD: String = var("PASSWORD").unwrap();`

Comment: @Rokit: Indeed. I also updated the snippet to provide a [MVCE], if we ask for it in questions, no reasons not to also provide it in answers :)

Comment: such a nice answer

Comment: @MatthieuM. I am noticing this example does not compile for me, saying `PASSWORD` does not implement `Debug`. I can only get to compile with: `let r: &str = &PASSWORD; println!("{r:?}");`

Comment: @ecoe: That's strange, it compiles for me on the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=759e003cb4e7225276064823e38cce06 . Can you reproduce your issue there?

Comment: I am on an ARM 64 processor, sorry I don't see how to set that in the playground or if it matters...

Comment: @ecoe: The type of processor shouldn't matter with regard to such a compilation error; I encourage you to ask a question of your own, with a full reproducible example and the exact text of the error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to put together a minimal reproducible answer. The only other difference is that I'm using tokio for asynchronous functions that call the `println!`

Answer (score 3):

All of what [Matthieu M. said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37406642/442760) is still correct, though nowadays you should use [`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) instead of `lazy_static`:

```rust
use std::sync::OnceLock;
use std::env::var;
fn password() -> &'static str {
    static PASSWORD: OnceLock<String> = OnceLock::new();
    PASSWORD.get_or_init(|| {
        var("PASSWORD").unwrap()
    })
}
```

and once it is stable or on nightly you can simplify to a `LazyLock`:

```rust
#![feature(lazy_cell)]
use std::sync::LazyLock;
use std::env::var;
static PASSWORD: LazyLock<String> = LazyLock::new(|| {
    var("PASSWORD").unwrap()
});
```

You can also save a word per variable (and possibly more depending on how the `String` actually is allocated) by using `Box<str>` instead of `String` and calling `.into()` on the strings, but it can involve an additional copying of the string contents.