# lazy_static raises error as "no rules expected the token"

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) crate to initialize some static variables which assigned values by reading some environment variables in `build.rs`. What I'm trying to achieve is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405835/populating-a-static-const-with-an-environment-variable-at-runtime-in-rust).

My code is following:

```
lazy_static! {

static _spdk_dir : String = match env::var("SPDK_DIR") {
    Ok(val) => val,
    Err(_e) => panic!("SPDK_DIR is not defined in the environment")
};

static _dpdk_dir: String = match env::var("DPDK_DIR") {
    Ok(val) => val,
    Err(_e) => panic!("DPDK_DIR is not defined in the environment")
};
}
```

After running `cargo test`, the compiler gives `error: no rules expected the token _spdk_dir`. I can get rid of this error by adding the keyword `ref` after `static` 
but doing so will lead another error when use the variable with `println!`:

```
println!("cargo:warning={}", _spdk_dir);
```

The error is `_spdk_dir doesn't implement std::fmt::Display`

I'm wondering how can I solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a lazy-static value claim to not implement a trait that it clearly implements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48114390/why-does-a-lazy-static-value-claim-to-not-implement-a-trait-that-it-clearly-impl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Under the hood, `lazy_static` creates a one-off object that dereferences to the actual value, which is computed lazily.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48115258/8492116) `_spdk_dir` is not a `String` but a value that evaluates to a `String`. You need to dereference the value to print it. One other thing you can do is use [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else) instead of the `match`:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref _spdk_dir: String = env::var("SPDK_DIR")
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("SPDK_DIR is not defined in the environment"));
    static ref _dpdk_dir: String = env::var("DPDK_DIR")
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("DPDK_DIR is not defined in the environment"))
}

println!("cargo:warning={}", *_spdk_dir);
```

(`ref` is part of `lazy_static`’s syntax, so you can’t leave it out.)