# no rules expected this token in macro call during initialization of static variable using lazy_static crate

Tags: rust, lazy-static

I am trying to initialize a static variable at runtime using `lazy_static` crate. But I'm getting `no rules expected the token E1` error while compiling. This is the link [lazy_static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405835/populating-a-static-const-with-an-environment-variable-at-runtime-in-rust) I followed

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static E1: f64 = (1.0 - f64::sqrt(1.5)) / (1.0 + f64::sqrt(0.5));
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", E1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `ref` token after `static`. This is just some custom grammar of `lazy_static` to express that this static works a bit different is only accessible by reference.

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref E1: f64 = (1.0 - f64::sqrt(1.5)) / (1.0 + f64::sqrt(0.5));
    //     ^^^
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", *E1);
    //             ^
}
```

That's also the reason you need to dereference the value as the static variable is an opaque type. In many contexts this is not required as the type implements `Deref<Target = f64>`. But here it is.

Also consider using [`once_cell`](https://github.com/matklad/once_cell) which lets you achieve the same thing but without macro.

Comment: which one would you prefer considering the performance(`lazy_static` or `once_cell`)?

Comment: @Harry I think performance-wise they are absolutely the same. (I haven't seen any benchmark, but this is fairly straight forward as far as I can tell). I prefer `once_cell` simply because I can get rid of a macro.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is: `static ref NAME: Type = expr;`. Note the `ref`.