# OnceCell not initialized in WASM module in browser

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm trying to use a `OnceCell` as a `const` in a Rust module compiled to web assembly.

```rust
use std::cell::OnceCell;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

const SENDER: OnceCell<i32> = OnceCell::new();

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get() -> i32 {
    SENDER.set(1).unwrap();

    let binding = SENDER;

    let Some(n) = binding.get() else {
        return -1;
    };

    *n
}
```

After setting the `OnceCell`, it is always empty. Even when getting the value immediately after setting it. I expect that it would contain the value that was set previously. In the above example, the `get` function always returns `-1`.

Here's a repro that shows the behaviour:

https://github.com/emfax/once_cell_test/tree/main

How can I use a `OnceCell` as a `const` in a Rust module compiled to web assembly?

Comment: All you need to do is replace `const` with `static`.

Comment: Actually, just noticed that you'll also need to use [`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) instead of `OnceCell`, or if you want to have one per thread, you can use [`thread_local`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html) This isn't really relevant for wasm (for now), but you'll need to do one of these for rust to accept it.

Comment: I changed it to `static` and `OnceLock`, but now there is this, `condvar wait not supported`. This is a tough one.

Comment: That sounds like a wasm-specific thing. I guess you'll need to use `thread_local` and `OnceCell`, which doesn't have that kind of synchronization.

Comment: drewtato correctly linked [Populating a static/const with an environment variable at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405835/populating-a-static-const-with-an-environment-variable-at-runtime-in-rust) as duplicate. I somehow managed to vote twice on that and undid that. Also the issue seems to be even bigger.